# Laravel + Apache + Routes Configuration Assets?

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following problem trying to put my app in production related to apache2 routes and Laravel routs.

What I have :

Server1 - Domain www.example.com <--- working with other apache and website

server2 - Domain www.example.com/myapp  <--- Server for my App Production

Laravel 5.5
Apache2
PHP 7.1

Apache confs

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html >
               AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.htpasswd file

    
        Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The problem is when I type on the browser www.example.com/myapp I access server2 but my css assets call server1 like www.example.com/css/app.css instead of calling www.example.com/myapp/app.css.

How can I solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Best

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can make use of the base element in the head section of your html/blade file. Like

```
<head>
    <base href="www.example.com/myapp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>
```

This will resolve the link to `www.example.com/myapp/css/app.css`

Read more at https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: I Bharat, thank you very much, yes I can do that but and then what to do with the routes I will need change every route post, get form.